# How to show specific results in R using Tukey test?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, tukey-hsd-test

I have a question about showing specific results in R. I am using a linear mixed model and checking the stats between each condition (adding 1, then adding 2, then adding 3...) in a repeated test, which the values are function of time. I have 5 repeated measurement on 6 materials and recorded the value as a function of time (dynamic measurement). I want to see the p values of condition 1 versus condition 2, condition 1 versus condition 3... condition 2 versus condition 3 and so on at each time point. 
Please see my structure,
[image]
Please see my code below,

```
library(nlme)
stresseffect= lme(stress~ Condition + Time, data=dt,random=~1| Specimen)
library(emmeans)
emmeans(stresseffect, list(pairwise ~ Condition+Time), adjust = "tukey")
```

When I run this, I obtain results as seen on the image below, however, I dont want to see results between 1,0 (condition 1 at time 0 sec) versus 2,1 (condition 2 at time 1 sec). I want comparison ie. 1,0 (condition 1 at time 0 sec) versus 2,0 or 1,1 versus 2,1 (condition 2 at time 0 sec), 4,1 (condition 4 at time 0 sec) verus 5,1 (condition 5 at time 0 sec) and so on. However, this code give me what I want plus all the time points, which is not my interest.

[image]

Helps are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `pairwise ~ Condition | Time`. See the documentation and vignettes that come with the package.

However, I note that the model is additive (no interaction). So every set of comparisons will be exactly the same. If that’s not what you want, then you need to include the interactions in the model.

Comment: I tried this as well and received same results in each time points and I didnt understand why it is giving the same values for each time point? I definitely need different p values for each time point comparison. I didnt understand very well what you meant by 'However, I note that the model is additive (no interaction). So every set of comparisons will be exactly the same. If that’s not what you want, then you need to include the interactions in the model.' May I ask what is the solution for my case?

Comment: Include the interaction of conditiuon and time in your model

Comment: `'library(emmeans)
ml=emmeans(MCLPassiven_Linear_mixed, list(pairwise ~ Condition| Time), adjust = "tukey")` Do you mean interaction like this? condition based on Time?? However, it always gives same results in each time point!!

Comment: Fit a different MODEL that includes Condition:Time

Comment: I am so sorry if I miss anything here. `stresseffect= lme(stress~ Condition + Time, data=dt,random=~1| Specimen)` This is my model and as you see, Condition and Time is a fixed effect while Specimen is a random. I do not understand how I should I fit what you mean. May I kindly ask if you can edit the code? Otherwise, unfortunately, I am not able to fix this issue :(. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Try the model `stresseffect= lme(stress ~ Condition + Time + Condition:Time, data = dt ,random = ~ 1| Specimen)`

Comment: thank you for your effort however, this doesnt provide the data I am interested in. This method compares only conditions with condition 1 (intercept) but not within eachother. I need to compare each condition with eachother at each second separately.

Comment: I think you should try to find a statistical consultant to help you and answer your questions face to face. Many of the issuse I see here have to do with using statistical methods correctly — not just getting software to work. Most campuses have a statistics department that can offer consulting help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This model was generated after a consultation of a statistical consultant. My issue here is not the model but the Tukey test results. The code is doing its job and providing me p values of each time point based on condition. However, it also provide comparison of different time points, i.e. 3,1 (condition 3 at 1 sec) - 2,6 (condition 2 at 6 sec). I only need results at each second.